# This preview build has expired. Please visit www.spotify.com to download a new version

Tags: spotify

When I run spotify I get the error message

`This preview build has expired. Please visit www.spotify.com to download a new version`

If I try to unistall it (on windows I get the same error message. I have version 0.8.2.10 installed

Seems im not the only, [with this probem](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Preview-build-expired-but-where-is-the-new/td-p/533) however the new preview build at
http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/preview/ gives me the expired error message when I try to install it

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please visit the page again - a new build was uploaded about 12 hours ago. If your browser is still showing 0.8.10.2, force-refresh the page and you'll see 0.8.10.3.